# Can I run capistrano not under root directory

Tags: capistrano

I tried to run the `cap production deploy` in a sub-directory and got the exception. Is there any way to run the command without being under root directory?

```
% cap production deploy                                                                                                      (git)-[develop]
Stage not set, please call something such as `cap production deploy`, where production is a stage you have defined.
```

Comment: Nope. Why do you need to run `cap` in a subdirectory? Perhaps we could find a workaround based on your use-case.